# verificar hora com php

Tags: php

Como verificar se a hora informada no input é mais que 24?

Tentei assim:

```
if ((strtotime($hora) > "24:00:00")) {

    echo "a hour não pode ser maior que 24";
}
```

Comment: não seria mais fácil fazer um explode na var delimitando : e verificar hora, minuto e segundo?

Comment: ou ainda usar a função nativa `DateTime`?

Comment: $strHora = substr("$hora", 0,2); If ($strHora>24){ echo "a hour não pode ser maior que 24"; }

Comment: Acho que você quer dizer mais de 23:59:59, se for horário do dia, pois depois disso é 00:00:00... A não ser que você esteja fazendo horas "contadas", tipo trabalhei *"80 horas apenas esta semana"*. Se puder explicar qual desses é o seu caso então irei criar uma resposta que seja para o correto para o seu caso.

Comment: preciso comprar 2 horas, a de ahora com a hora que esta no BD no formato 00:00:00, preciso saber sé a hora de logra e menor.

Comment: A sugestão do amigo @leo deve funcionar perfeitamente para seu caso.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio tem como postar um exemplo? ai já marco sua resposta

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo posta com resposta para eu marcar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$strHora = substr("$hora", 0,2);
If ($strHora>24){
echo "a hour não pode ser maior que 24";
}

mas o correto seria 

$strHora = substr("$hora", 0,2);
If ($strHora>=24){
echo "a hour não pode ser maior que 24";
}

já que ninguém diz 24:00:00 e sim zero hora, então no if seria $strHora > 23
```

Comment: ok, mais como comparo 2 datas? tipo se 10:00 e menor que 20:00.

Comment: se transoformar a hora em `timestamp`

Comment: isso não foi especificado na pergunta rs

Comment: @MarceloBonifazioeu sei, a dúvida surgiu agora hahahah, mais vlw